# Unwanted character appears during XSS attack

Tags: html, xss

So I am performing an XSS attack on a VM for a school assignment and it is successful. However, there are two characters "> that are printed to the screen underneath where I am attacking and I would like to hide them so that the user can't see them

I have something like this:

```
<input type="someType" name="someName" 
value="&quot;/&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert('Hello');&lt;/script&gt;"/>
```

I assume it has something to do with the closing of the tag. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your script needs some modifications

Try the script below

```
<input type="someType" name="someName" 
value="&lt;script&gt;alert('Hello')&lt;/script&gt;"/>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work and just prints out my script to the screen instead of executing it.